# Powershell to start/stop with arg

Tags: powershell

I've written the following function in test.ps1 and I would like to make a choise when running thsi script to start/stop/.. :

```
function getState($SeviceName) { 
    $server = @('host_1', 'host_2')

    # get status 
    $server | % {Write-Host "verify: $_"; Get-Service -ComputerName $_ -Name SeviceName
}
```

1. I would like to provide `$ServiceName` as argument (with stdin) how can I do it?  => somthing like choose 1 to start 2 to stop ...
2. To use switch/case in Powershell

   ```
   $doAction = {"Stop-Service", "Start-service"}
   $server | % {Write-Host "verify: $_"; Get-Service -ComputerName $_ -Name SeviceName | $doAction}
   ```

How do I use the switch to select start or stop?

Comment: `-Name SeviceName` -> `-Name $SeviceName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that will do what you're asking for:

```
function Get-State {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType('System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory)]
        [ValidateSet('Start', 'Stop', 'Get')]
        [string] $Action,

        [Parameter(Position = 1, ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $ServiceName
    )

    begin {
        $serverList = @('host_1', 'host_2')
    }

    process {
        foreach ($server in $serverList) {
            try {
                $svc = Get-Service -ComputerName $server -Name $ServiceName -ErrorAction Stop
            } catch {
                throw "Failed to find service $ServiceName on $server! $PSItem"
            }

            switch ($Action) {
                'Start' { $svc | Start-Service -PassThru }
                'Stop'  { $svc | Stop-Service -Force -PassThru }
                default { $svc }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It utilizes advanced function features and attributes to take pipeline input (`stdin` in your words).  I'd suggest [reading this documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: @Lika I forgot to add `process{}` to my example.  It should work as expected now.

Comment: @TheIncorrrigible : sorry I'm not familar with powershell in other languages we call the script with or without arg, here if I try to just call test.ps it doesn't return anything whereas I'm expecting to be asked to provide  arg

Comment: @Lika I added a `Mandatory` attribute to the `$ServiceName` now so you should get prompted for it if you execute it without arguments.

Comment: to run I have just to call .\test.ps1 wich contain this function riight ? because as I said it doesn't return anything

Comment: @Lika No, you'd need to call the function after it's defined `} Get-State`.  If you want to call it like that, save the contents into a file without `function ... {` and the ending `}`.  I've updated it again so it'll prompt you for both the service name and which action to take.  The action can be tab-completed.

Answer (score 1):

You can add argument to a script by adding parameters to it.
On the top of your script file put:

```
Param
(
    [parameter()]
    [String[]]$YourArgumentVariable

    [parameter()]
    [switch] $MySwitch
)
```

With a function it goes right after the function definition. So in your case:

```
function getState($SeviceName) { 
    Param
    (
        [parameter()]
        [String[]]$server

        [parameter()]
        [switch] $MySwitch
    )
    # get status 
    $server | % {Write-Host "verify: $_"; Get-Service -ComputerName $_ -Name SeviceName
}
```

A switch basically sets a boolean to true or false.
So in this if you call the script with -MySwitch it will set the variable $MySwitch to true. Else it will remain false.

Don Jones has written a [good getting started article on paramters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554301.aspx) that I would recommend you checking out.

Do note that there are loads of things you can define in the paramter. Like if you want to make sure it is always filled you can set

```
 [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
```

This is just one of many examples of what you can do with paramters.

Comment: You may want to rewrite your demo function `getState` because there are quite a few syntax errors/typos in there..